# Fetch session details

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, session-cookies, powerquery

I want to get the session id & csfrtoken from the url: https://www.screener.in/api/company/6596449/quick_ratios/
below is the screenshot of the values.

[image]

Also, I tried the below code in vba, but not getting response. please guide, Note the account is a dummy account only to fetch the details.

```
Sub test()
 Dim user As String
 Dim pwd As String
 Dim path As String
 user = "rajesh2.gade@gmail.com"
 pwd = "Rain@123"
 path = "https://www.screener.in/api/company/6596449/quick_ratios/"
 Debug.Print httpGET(path, user, pwd)
End Sub

Public Function httpGET(fn As String, _
        Optional authUser As String = vbNullString, _
        Optional authPass As String = vbNullString) As String
    pHtml = fn
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Call oHttp.Open("GET", pHtml, False)
    If (authUser <> vbNullString) Then
    ' need to do basic authentication
    ' acknowledgement to http://pastie.org/1192157
        oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        oHttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        oHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + _
            EncodeBase64(authUser + ":" + authPass)
    End If
    Call oHttp.send("")
    Debug.Print oHttp.getAllResponseHeaders
    httpGET = oHttp.responseText
    Set oHttp = Nothing
End Function


Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String


  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  EncodeBase64 = Application.Clean(objNode.text)

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: If parsing content from that site after logging in is what you want, I've a solution for you. Btw, are [this](https://freeimage.host/i/iwZybI) the data you are after?

Comment: @SIM, thats a good news for me, been trying from last week, yes after logging in only I need that content. Also Can I get those session details too.Thank you so much Sim for the response.

Comment: @SIM , any suggestion on my comments to your  respnose below....regarding session id and csrf token...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the value of sessionid to login to that site. Csrftoken is necessary, though. However, the following is how you can log in to that site and access the content available in there.

```
Sub ScrapeAfterLogin()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.screener.in/api/company/6596449/quick_ratios/"
    Const Link$ = "https://www.screener.in/login/"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, sParams As String
    Dim oHttp As Object, sToken$

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", Url, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        sToken = Html.querySelector("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").getAttribute("value")
        sParams = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" & sToken & "&next=%2Fapi%2Fcompany%2F6596449%2Fquick_ratios%2F&username=rajesh2.gade%40gmail.com&password=Rain%40123"
        
        .Open "POST", Link, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.screener.in/login/"
        .setRequestHeader "Origin", "https://www.screener.in"
        .send (sParams)
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        MsgBox .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

To get the session id, you have to create a session, reuse the same session throughout all the requests and then find that session id in the cookies. I don't know how to reuse the same session in vba. However, the following is a python version of achieving the same.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_url = 'https://www.screener.in/api/company/6596449/quick_ratios/'
login_url = 'https://www.screener.in/login/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '',
    'next': '/api/company/6596449/quick_ratios/',
    'username': 'rajesh2.gade@gmail.com',
    'password': 'Rain@123',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(start_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    params['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = soup.select_one("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']")['value']
    s.headers['Origin'] = 'https://www.screener.in'
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.screener.in/login/'
    resp = s.post(login_url,data=params)
    print(s.cookies.items())
```

Output:

```
[('csrftoken', 'y64L6KeQfJiDvTMcsRQNlLCGYtfEVj82'), ('sessionid', 'e06akkv5yodjag6nf9tqrz5hex9wx99w')]
```

Comment: yes testing now to fetch the data..

Comment: you are spot on, but  the reason I  need csfrtoken and sessonid as I am passing them as cookie information in  power query Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Web.Contents("https://www.screener.in/api/company/6596449/quick_ratios//", [Headers=[#"accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate", #"accept-language"="en-US,en", #"user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36", cookie="csrftoken=verlKZxv02rwj0KgvrY9UnqBO2vUotj6; sessionid=d3bmr16zt3253lppqzv1o7q9dradda1l"]]))}).

Comment: do u suggest I can replace the cookie with "csrfmiddlewaretoken" or sToken in place of cookie, I am iterating few scripts hence using power query to fetch all ata time.

Comment: Till now I manually logging in and copying both csrftoken and sessionid to use it in excel power query..

Comment: Check out the edit @Kiran.